# How to move SharePoint 2010 list workflows from QA to Staging

Tags: 2013, powershell, designer-workflow, visio

Is there a way to move SharePoint 2010 list workflows from one environment to another `without the use of "SharePoint Designer"`?

I know how to Export it to visio and do stuff but my main issue is, it all requires the use of designer. We don't have permission to open designer on production, hence require a way to send 2010 workflows across the environment via PowerShell or any other automated method.

Comment: You need get the powwershell help here. Assuming that you WFis a feature activated and wsp is in solutions gallery , write ps script for activating this WF solution.$wfTemplate=$web.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByName("yourWF",$culture)

Comment: How to create wsp for a 2010 list workflow

Comment: "We don't have permission to open designer on production". What do you mean by that ?  does that mean.,you wont be able to access the production site URL from your SP D, which is installed on your desktop /or any dev.env where SP D is installed ?

Comment: Yea, we won't be able to access it, use of designer is blocked EVERYWHERE

Comment: so,there is no way to deploy list workflows on a different env. without using SP D. If in any case, you have found out the approach please share here, so that the spdev. community can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your list workflows were created with SharePoint Designer (SPD).  If this is the case, then they cannot easily be moved between environments without some very tedious work within SPD that requires updating GUIDs in the xml based source files that define your workflows and their logic.

Comment: Yea i know..I am trying to automate it somehow..

Comment: I think once we get the SPD workflow as a wsp in the solutions gallery, we can easily write the PS to activate/deploy in any site collection/any sp 2013 farm. I have done the same for my SP 2013 on-premises env where the number of site collections were 46 and my doc_approval workflow is deployed with the help of PS.

Comment: @SaMolPP doesn't work for 2010 workflows.

Comment: Can you check this link :  https://meera999.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/deploy-a-workflow-as-a-wsp-file-sharepoint-server-2010/ .  Its possible in SP D 2010 to save as wsp file and you can further use my PS script for automating those steps.